# Can I specify that an interface will share the keys of another?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces that I want to share the same keys, but not the same values. Imagine that the first interface (`Thing`) is from an external library and the second interface (`ThingOptions`) is in my project.

```js
interface Thing {
  foo(value: number): void;
  bar(value: string): void;
  someOtherKey: null;
}

interface ThingOptions {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}
```

Is there any way to assert that the keys of `ThingOptions` are a subset of the keys of `Thing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to get some compile-time checking on this but I think all of them require a little bit of repetition of the `ThingOptions` name.

One way is to make a `KeysFrom<T, U>` which takes a type `T` and a candidate type `U`, which is only compatible with `U` if the keys of `U` are a subset of those of `T` (meaning that `T` can have keys that `U` doesn't have, but `U` can't have keys that `T` doesn't have):

```
type KeysFrom<T, U> = { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? U[K] : never }
```

So `KeysFrom<{a: string}, {a: number}>` just becomes `{a: number}`, which `{a: number}` extends.  But `KeysFrom<{a: string}, {b: number}` becomes `{b: never}`, which `{b: number}` does not extends.  Then you declare that `ThingOptions` extends `KeysFrom<Thing, ThingOptions>`.  It's a recursive constraint.  Let's see it:

```
interface ThingOptions extends KeysFrom<Thing, ThingOptions> {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}
```

That works.

```
interface BadThingOptions extends KeysFrom<Thing, BadThingOptions> { // error!
//        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- properties of type "bap" are incompatible
    foo: number;
    bap: string;
}
```

And that fails to compile, as you presumably want.

---

Another thing you can do which isn't recursive is to move the check to its own line:

```
type KeysAreSubset<
    T,
    U extends { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? U[K] : never }
> = true;
```

Here, `KeysAreSubset<T, U>` evaluates to `true` always, but `U` is now constrained to `KeysFrom<T, U>`.  If you use `KeysAreSubset<ThingOptions, U>` with a bad `U`, you'll get an error:

```
interface ThingOptions {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}

type ThingOptionsIsOkay = KeysAreSubset<Thing, ThingOptions>;

interface BadThingOptions { 
    foo: number;
    bap: string;
}

type BadThingOptionsIsNotOkay = KeysAreSubset<Thing, BadThingOptions>; // error!
//  Types of property 'bap' are incompatible. -----> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

Both of those work, but they both require you to rewrite the name `ThingOptions`, and they both require you to jump through some hoops to use properly.  Still, it might work for your use case.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMicjAPbkAUAbnADYCuEAXMiIwLYBG0AlGxrlgAEwDcRUsm5wotBszYBnMFGwDkQ0ROKkl5ThADyYdNADSEAJ5sO9ejoC+RIiDiGlAB0QoAShARGKCVgGggAYXIQFSg4UDA8F10SMCtPFEsrJQAxKAMAHlQAGmQAVQA+ZABePGQAbXNkUGQAa2tyGDKAXTZGiAAPSBARJVb2ztRkAH4yhq7kWwgwqGRnQklSeOh4JDRMECwjTzBgKNGBoZHkTJy8zkL9rBKMbCOTs8qCZKkySlsuXhQHQ-UgyKDKVTYYGkNYbEhbWA+ZAAITgIheBzep2iyAuEGGoxuuQKGKeKLRpKxH1qAHoabioHkoABCOE-OlSAB+3J5vL5yHyAFpBchPHl0lAThBRh1kKl0sgAEQyTyK5CyFCgBAGbwnbj0CBsqQUcj-HjQaEglUQtQHS2rJKwwhuDzeXYAZQg3likHCZgQLUS62+8oy1iUAEEoBB3YxuEoIGB8kbSMUUyRSrjBvirrh6o1mm0rLLSj1rlnLqMi7LJjNSnMFuwltAHd9KjVVMwdGyETsUJTjtjRl8QSQTWbAfapGCbVC2U6pKG9q9B2cAJJKIwtOBWarXcNRmNxhNJ0nPR5U6LlbvfXtI1Hoi+rnEj0fj9gAi3p6RwTyzu3zkki5pCgD4Du80QbgAcuQYBbjue43IesbxomDzYCUYFPhBSjXsgHLQEyrLfByaAgTKnRiuQEqpMgADkKp0eq0ZNCA2qcLqwD6hAAB0yDCgJlR8sJvKOkQQA)

Comment: This is a really informative answer nonetheless, but you didn't include any consideration for the  `someOtherKey: null;` line in the OP's snippet. If I got it right, a ThingOptions with that property would still be valid with your approach, right?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't explicit about it... yes, you can leave keys out, you just can't add extra keys.  So yes, `someOtherKey` would be allowed.

Comment: I would say the correct answer to the question is `no, you can't`, like the one from @baHI bellow, but yours is the most informative and the closest you can get to what the OP asked. Maybe it would be more clear if you added a TL;DR.

Comment: This answer proves that "no" is not correct. The recursive check does exactly what is requested: assert that the keys of `ThingOptions` are a subset of the keys of `Thing`.

Comment: The answer to "is there any way to assert that the keys of `ThingOptions` are a subset of the keys of `Thing`?" is "yes, if you do the following not-so-obvious things".  It's only "no" if the question is "is there any *simple* and *built-in* way", but I don't see that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: **NO, you can't.**
Those 2 interfaces are different, their properties are of different types.

So while you can't use TypeScript to do some safe-guard, you could do this:

```
  let a = {
    foo: v => "my string return value",
    bar: v => "2"
  } as Thing;

  let b = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: "2"
  } as ThingOptions;

  let propertiesOfA = Object.keys(a);
  let propertiesOfB = Object.keys(b);

  // and now you just have to compare if every item in the 1st array is inside the 2nd one... so possibly creating some function of comparing 2 objects this way is the solution you need...
```

Comment: The intent is to help with development (eg. avoiding mistakes in the keys of `ThingOptions`). Runtime checking is out of scope, IMO.

Comment: So then the answer is NO, as those 2 interfaces are DIFFERENT. If the foo and bar would be on both interfaces of same type, then you could write something like this: interface Thing extends ThingOptions { someOtherKey: any }

Comment: The issue with that approach is that the question specifies that `Thing` is in an external library, and thus can't (or at least shouldn't) be modified. For now, we'll just assume that "No" is the correct answer. I'll accept it if no better answers come along.